# what is com.squareup.okhttp package used in Cordova Android App

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I've just imported Cordova Android App into Android studio. I see two packages used by Cordova:

```
1) com.squareup.okhttp
2) org.apache.cordova
```

As I understand `org.apache.cordova` is the main library used by Cordova applications since it contains `CordovaActivity` main class. What is the purpose of `com.squareup.okhttp` package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> An HTTP & SPDY client for Android and Java applications
>
> HTTP is the way modern applications network. It’s how we exchange data
>   & media. Doing HTTP efficiently makes your stuff load faster and saves
>   bandwidth.
>
> OkHttp is an HTTP client that’s efficient by default:
>   SPDY support allows all requests to the same host to share a socket.
>   Connection pooling reduces request latency (if SPDY isn’t available).
>   Transparent GZIP shrinks download sizes.
>   Response caching avoids the network completely for repeat requests.

[OKHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) is an OpenSource library for Http connections.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know or can suppose why Cordova hardcodes files of the library to the project instead of specifying it as a dependency?

Comment: @Maximus No, I use Java for Android development and not HTML :) You could try asking that as a question and hopefully somebody will give you an answer

Comment: Yeah, sure, I think I'll ask that question. Thanks!

Comment: Please post the link to the question here so I can also read the answer. :)

Comment: Yep, here [it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27090740/why-cordova-creates-project-with-hardcoded-com-squareup-okhttp-instead-of-specif).