# why Cordova creates project with hardcoded com.squareup.okhttp instead of specifying it as a dependency

Tags: android, cordova

I've just imported Cordova Android App into Android studio. I see two packages used by Cordova:

1) com.squareup.okhttp
2) org.apache.cordova

`com.squareup.okhttp` package is the OKHttp - an OpenSource library for Http connections. Cordova uses this library in `CordovaResourceApi` class. My question is why Cordova team included that library as a hardcoded library instead of specifying it as a build dependency for CordovaLib library?

Comment: Until recently, cordova lib itself was being distributed as a jar! I think you have a point, but SO is not the place to talk about, I would go and post this to cordova dev mailing list or sth.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use your advice and write them.

Comment: Did you end up asking them why it was included?  I'm running into a problem because of this.

Comment: Hey, no, I didn't do that. What's your problem?

Comment: Did you get why cordova used okhttp ?what is the use of cordova with okhttp?

Comment: Any news on this? I'd love to know if Lets Encrypt encrypted backed are still usable after June 2021 with Cordova apps (https://letsencrypt.org/2020/11/06/own-two-feet.html)